# Race condition while showing and hiding FAB with AnimationUtils

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, floating-action-button, animationutils

In an Android app allowing user logins via social networks I show and hide a `FAB` using the following code:

[image: app screenshot]

```
public abstract class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    private FloatingActionButton mFab;
    private Animation mShowFab;
    private Animation mHideFab;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mShowFab = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(getContext(), false);
        mShowFab.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                mFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

        mHideFab = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(getContext(), true);
        mHideFab.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void showFab(boolean show) {
        boolean visible = mFab.isShown();

        if (show && !visible) {
                mFab.startAnimation(mShowFab);
        } else if (!show && visible) {
                mFab.startAnimation(mHideFab);
        }
    }
```

This works well, when I call the above `showFab` method slow enough.

Before starting any animation I check for current `FloatingActionButton` visibility, so that the animation is played only **once** - even if I call for example `showFab(true)` several times in a row.

**My problem:**

When a `LoginFragment` is shown in my app, I first send a request to a `ServiceIntent` to fetch user data from SQLite and call the following method to set my UI to a "waiting" state:

```
private void setBusy(boolean busy) {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(busy ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    showFab(!busy);
}
```

Almost immediately a response from SQLite comes back - via a `LocalBroadcastManager` and I call the above method again: `setBusy(false)`.

And then the error occurs and the `FAB` is not visible.

If I replace the `FAB` method by animation-less code everything works fine:

```
private void showFab(boolean show) {
    mFab.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

But with animation - a racing condition seems to occur.

As a workaround I have tried canceling both animations - but this does not help:

```
private void showFab(boolean show) {
    mShowFab.cancel();
    mShowFab.reset();

    mHideFab.cancel();
    mHideFab.reset();

    boolean visible = mFab.isShown();

    if (show && !visible) {
            mFab.startAnimation(mShowFab);
    } else if (!show && visible) {
            mFab.startAnimation(mHideFab);
    }
}
```

Please suggest what could be done here.

I have stepped through my app in debugger numerous times already. The `setBusy` (and `showFab`) are called only twice when the Fragment is shown, but both calls happen very quickly - and the `FAB` is not shown -

**First run:**

[image: 1st run]

**Second run:**

[image: 2nd run]

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately, making the method `synchronized` does not help either - the `FAB` stays hidden:

```
private synchronized void showFab(boolean show) {
    mShowFab.cancel();
    mShowFab.reset();

    mHideFab.cancel();
    mHideFab.reset();

    boolean visible = mFab.isShown();

    if (show && !visible) {
        mFab.startAnimation(mShowFab);
    } else if (!show && visible) {
        mFab.startAnimation(mHideFab);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your animations run in separate threads. This leads to a race condition as you said.

Here's whats going on:
showFab is fired with true, then false.

- The mShowFab onAnimationStart method executes and sets the FAB to visible.
- The mHideFab onAnimationStart method executes and does nothing.
- The mShowFab onAnimationEnd method executes and does nothing.
- The mHideFab onAnimationEnd method executes and sets the FAB to invisible.
- annnd you end up with an invisible FAB that should be visible.

The variables in your second run show that the mShowFab animation will never run.

You should be able to resolve the race condition by listening for the end of the hide animation. Something like this:

```
private void showFab(boolean show) {
    if (show) {
        // if you have an animation currently running and you want to show the fab 
        if (mFab.getAnimation() != null && !mFab.getAnimation().hasEnded()) {
            // then wait for it to complete and begin the next one
            mFab.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mFab.startAnimation(mShowFab);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            mFab.startAnimation(mShowFab);
        }
    } else {
        mFab.startAnimation(mHideFab);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you +1. However, if you state that the animations run in separate threads, then things might change **between** the check `!mFab.getAnimation().hasEnded()` and setting a listener for the animation. So I don't think your code is a good solution.

Comment: After digging through the source of `Animation` I am confident that this is thread safe. The `AnimationListener` callbacks are posted to the main thread message queue and the `hasEnded()` check also runs on the main thread.

Comment: Don't you need to stop the animation at some point? mine seems to repeat endlessly if I use this code

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to point out is that there is nothing like racing condition. The right terminology is just **race condition**. Keep this in mind for the future ;-)

I suppose you are using a BroadcastReceiver to receive messages and that you have created the object and tell it to run in a separate thread because of the animation. This means that your showFab method can be called twice in one time. To handle this, define the method as [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, making the `showFab` method `synchronized` does not help - the `FAB` is still hidden. Something else must be going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution -

First, using `synchronized` does not help here, because the animations run in the same thread.

My solution has been to introduce a separate `boolean` variable to hold the intended final FAB state (visible or not visible):

```
private FloatingActionButton mFab;
private boolean mFabVisible;
private Animation mShowFab;
private Animation mHideFab;

private void showFab(boolean show) {

    if (show && !mFabVisible) {
        mFab.startAnimation(mShowFab);
    } else if (!show && mFabVisible) {
        mFab.startAnimation(mHideFab);
    }

    mFabVisible = show;
}
```

Also, I think another possibility might have been to call `mFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` twice - as in the below code. But I haven't really tested it:

```
    mShowFab = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(getContext(), false);
    mShowFab.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            mFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    mHideFab = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(getContext(), true);
    mHideFab.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
```